# How to change font size and name of selected dimensions in drawing

Tags: vba, fonts, catia

I would like to change the font name and font size of all dimensions in the drawing.
I tried to select dimensions using this code: (dimensions are selected, but I don't know how to enter the font name and font size change)

```vb
Set oDrwDoc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set oSheets = oDrwDoc.Sheets
Set oSheet = oSheets.ActiveSheet
Set oViews = oSheet.Views
For vc = 3 To oViews.Count 'scan all views for dimensions except main view and background views
    Set oView = oSheet.Views.Item(vc)
    oView.Activate
    Set oDims = oView.Dimensions
    For dc = 1 To oDims.Count
        Set oDim = oDims.Item(dc)
        Set oDimVal = oDim.GetValue
        oDim.SetFontName 0, 0, "Monospac821 BT"
    Next 'dc
Next 'vc
```

Comment: AFAIK that is not possible. Therefore use a proper drawing standard for creating the drawing.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and I use EKL to modify them. EKL has this option.

```vb
let oDim (DrwDimension)

oDim.FontName =  "Arial (TrueType)"
oDim.FontSize = 3
```